# htaccess rewrite help needed, url /123 to /123/

Tags: mod-rewrite

Currently we have rewrite configured to make urls like: /wallpaper/123 but would instead like the rewrite to /wallpaper/123/

### Problem:

I need the existing links to be redirected properly from "/wallpaper/123" to "/wallpaper/123/"

### Current htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tvoioboi.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://tvoioboi.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your rewrite rules here, give us something to work with :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of...

```
RewriteRule (.+)[^/]*$ $1/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it based on your comment with:
RewriteRule ^wallpaper/(.[^/]+)$ /wallpaper/$1/ [R=301,L]